# Installing upstream NuGet packages from my Azure DevOps Artifacts feed (to get them saved in that feed) has no effect

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, nuget

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/consume?view=azure-devops#consume-packages) for consuming packages from [upstream sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops) in our Azure DevOps Artifacts feed says to install packages from the NuGet Package Manager Console and then those packages and all their dependencies will be saved in our Artifacts feed and will be visible on the NuGet page in Visual Studio.

But when I do exactly that, NuGet says that the packages are already installed and does nothing. If I try deleting my packages directory and clearing the local NuGet caches first, NuGet says I have to do a NuGet restore first. And if I try to do the restore, NuGet says it can't find the packages in the package source.

Is there some undocumented step that I'm missing?

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some undocumented step that I'm missing?

You are not missing any undocumented steps.

When you restore the packages but not find the packages in the packages in the package source, you should make sure:

- Your Azure DevOps Artifacts feed has enable the upstream sources.
- **All those packages in the Azure DevOps Artifacts feed or the upstream sources**.

If you do not enable upstream sources or your packages are not exists in the Azure DevOps Artifacts feed or the upstream sources, you will get the error find the packages in the package source.

If you have confirm above but still have this issue, please share the error log in your question, I will check it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Am having the same issue. The nuget.org packages are available in the feed even after adding it as upstream source. Could you please help?